# Static or nonstatic action in mvc?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

i want to ask you about mvc. How it works. So, this is simple example(I don't use any frameworks)

in Controller(Servlet):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String page = null;
    AbstractCommand action;

    action = ActionFactory.getAction(request);// get command from factory
    page = action.execute(request, response); 
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(page);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

for action we create a common interface(Strategy pattern):

```
public interface AbstractAction {

    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

Simple Action(Example):

```
public class HelloAction implements AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        //....(some actions to modify request)
        String page = "/main.jsp";
        return page;
    }   
}
```

And now, our factory:

```
public class ActionFactory {

    private enum Actions{
        HELLO;
    }

    public static AbstractAction getAction(HttpServletRequest request){
        String action = request.getParameter("action");//take parameter from jsp
        Actions actionEnum = Actions.valueOf(action.toUpperCase());
        switch (actionEnum) {
        case HELLO:
            return new HelloAction(); 
        }
    }
}
```

We came to the place where I am in confused. Servlet is initialized only once, and only one for all requests. Just forwards requests to the actions where we modify request or response. But, we create NEW instance of the class for every request. Here can occur memory overflow!? Or not?

Can we make these actions static(static method, one for all request)? If two requests come at the same time what will happen to them?
What do you think about this, please share your experience.

P.S. sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Singleton pattern to get the instance of the Action class ?

1. Just add some `abstact getInstance()` method in `AbstractAction`.
2. Make every implementation provide its own instance.
3. In every implementation class, use Singleton pattern so that only one instance exists.
4. Make sure no action class stores any data related to a specific request.

Comment: I know how to do it but there another question. Code that I shown in a question, based on examples on MVC. But I think this approach has a drawback. So I'm ask, can this any reason? I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Creating new instance of every request can create problem if the number of concurrent request is high. Most (may be all) uses Singelton pattern to control the number of instances.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood the jsp, the whole thing is stateless, if u access the servlet by http request, the servlet will be created in a new instance.
After leaving the servlet by .forward(), it will be released by garbage collection.

2,3,...,n requests = 2,3,...,n servlets.

by forwarding to a jsp, the only way to access the servlet from jsp is a new http request = new servlet. ( will move to the doPost method)

Comment: you are mistaken. The life cycle of a servlet is controlled by the container in which the servlet has been deployed. Servlet cannot be destroyed by garbage collector. See more servlet lifecycle.